# Is it OK to manually pop view controllers which are not currently visible (app in different tab) on memory warning?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller

I have a "memory management vs user experience" or just a silly question. Let's imagine a `UITabBarController` based app with two tabs. While user is in 1st tab, a memory warnings arrives and 2nd tab's view controller handles `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Let's also assume that 2nd tab has a pushed view controller. Questions:

1. is it OK to manually pop VC in 2nd
   tab with
   `popViewControllerAnimated:` when
   memory warning is issued?
2. Is it considered a bad UX or bad
   mem-mgmt idea? I think the user may
   be surprised with what he/she sees
   after switching back to 2nd tab, but
   if I don't pop that VC the user will
   see just a blank screen. If user taps 'Back', 2nd tab VC will reload itself anyway (restart life-cycle with `viewDidLoad:` and it's better than the app being killed by iOS).

The only flaw I see in above approach is when my pushed VC also pushed some VC. Then, the code would complicate... and if there was anything else pushed, it would complicate further leaving me with hard to maintain spaghetti code like that:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    UIViewController *pushedController = [self.navigationController visibleViewController];
    if ([pushedController isKindOfClass:[MyController class]]) {            
        // POP
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    } else {
        // MyController pushed something
        UIViewController *innerController = [pushedController.navigationController visibleViewController];
        if ([innerController isKindOfClass:[MyOtherController class]]) {
            [innerController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            // Final POP
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    }

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

What's your approach/advice? Maybe there's already a simple approach for this and I overlooked it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any undefined behaviour would surely mean bad user experience. When your controller gets a memory warning the best approach would be to release any cached images, views(which are not in view), variables(not in use). You may want to design the app in such a way that memory management in the above scenario would not lead to undefined behaviour. Your app may not want to hog up all the memory and not know how to release it.

It should be able to release the unwanted memory and handle the warning. You may want to specify what kind of data you are holding inorder to get a more specific response here.

Comment: you're right, however, for this given controller, I cannot release anything, otherwise, that controller would have to reload itself (which is fine if no VC is pushed). What if my app received critical memory warning? In that case view would be forcefully unloaded by iOS, right? I think it should clean up it's navigation stack in that case, correct? Does it makes sense to add `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` to `viewDidUnload`?

Comment: Well would you like it if any app did that. As developers we wouldn't mind as long as we know why we are doing it. But a end user may obviously not like it. Btw i would totally understand if i would have to use your app ;-).

Comment: yes, end-user perspective is something that counts most in the end :) I think, I'll move navigation stack clean-up to `viewDidUnload` - if view is being unloaded, it should not matter, I think. Thanks a lot for you answers :)

Comment: later on, if no one posts a better answer, I'll accept yours - it guided me quite well :)

Comment: Always there are techniques to use less memory especially while loading images etc. You can google or search here to get more info.